# How to see file name in Finder search results using macOS Sierra

Tags: finder, macos

It appears that Finder search results are displayed using metadata instead of the file name. I want to know the file name for the file in the results.

You can see in the first screenshot there are 3 files that simply say "Altitude" in the Name column, which is extremely unhelpful. The second screenshot shows the folder they are in outside of Finder's search results.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but may help: you can see the actual file name of a file by selecting it and opening Get Info (command-`I`), or the inspector (option-command-`I`) if you want it to update as your selection changes.

Comment: Also not an answer, but selecting an mp3 and pressing spacebar will give you artist and title if they're set in the tags.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGdPf.png there is no such thing as this image in Sierra? the search results are also so much better in Mojave it seems. The search results in list view are shown with full name.

Comment: Is there a proper solution to this in Catalina? This is incredibly annoying if you have multiple songs with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Finder** > **View** > **Show Path Bar** - in your search the path will show at the bottom - that should help.

[image: Screenshot of the Show Path Bar menu option]

Comment: This is not a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Open finder, go to finder preferences in the left corner.

Go to advanced.It should appear a window like this:

[image]

Select show all filename extensions and you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question. I do have that checked already and macOS ignores it in the search results. You can see in my screenshot they are not displaying the filename at all.